# Hibernate JPA: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist

The model contains:

`StationSecondaire` **class**:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "station_principal_id", nullable = false)
public StationPrincipale getStationPrincipale() {
    return this.stationPrincipale;
}
```

and 
`StationPrincipale` **class**:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stationPrincipale")
public Set<StationSecondaire> getStationSecondaires() {
    return this.stationSecondaires;
}
```

And i tried to obtain an existent `StationPrincipale`  in database by:

```
StationPrincipale sp = spDAO.findStationByName("Some name");
//Some staff
StationSecondaire ssNew = new StationSecondaire(0, ((Station) obj).getValue().toString(), null,((Station) obj).getId());
ssNew.setStationPrincipale(sp); 

//staff
ssDAO.persist(ssNew);
```

After that, I created some new `StationSecondaire` object and I attached them to the `sp`.

When i tried to persist `StationSecondaire` object, i got that **error**:

```
detached entity passed to persist: StationPrincipale
```

How can i fix it so that i can **add** an `StationSecondaire` object attached to an existent `StationPrincipale` one?

Comment: can you please provide more code? especially where you save the entity..

Comment: I made an update to the question, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`persist` is for new values, so use `merge` instead of it, because `sp` already exists.